# Android Device Monitor not opening in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-device-monitor

When I am trying to open Android Device Monitor.

The below error is coming, I am using Android studio 2.2.2

I am not able to understand what is happening. I have tried 10 times and each time it is coming.
[image: I am not able to understand what is happening. I have tried 10 times and each time it is coming.]

Comment: have you checked said log file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Running Android studio in Administrative mode has resoled the issue.